# How to Check the variable value is [""] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Example:
When I check a variable containing this value [""] it returns false.

```
var th=[]
th.push("");
if($("#multiselect").val()==th)
```

It returns always false.

Thank you.

Edit 1:
changed Var to var. It was a typo.

Edit 2:
Actually, the problem I faced was I was trying to get the value from a multi-select input. The multi-select input sometimes returns values as [""] even I haven't selected any values basically it's a plugin. So I was confused and I thought [""] is a fixed primitive value like 1, 10, "bla blah",.. So I tried to compare it with the same array as the right-hand side of the '=' operator.
It was stupid. Now I posted the solution to my problem and I explained my stupidity.

Comment: Arrays don't equal other arrays of the same value, so `[] == []` is `false`. You should provide a little more detail; it's difficult to tell what you are trying to do. Are you trying to determine if an array contains empty strings?

Comment: You compare if value is an array! You could try with `...val() == th[0] )` but why using an array anyways in this case?

Comment: You can accept answer, it will help others to find the best possible solution for this type of problem.

Comment: As Mark said, object comparisons are not related when using = operator. I updated my question and I answered what I was expecting.

Comment: Anushman, I posted an applicable answer and marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a couple of days when I posted this question. Now I can feel how stupid this question was.

Anyway, I'm answering this question so it might help others.

**Answer to my question:**

When two non-primitive datatype objects(which is the Array here) are compared using an assignment operator, it compares its reference of the object. So the object creation of both arrays would be different. If I want to check the array has [""] value, I should do something like the below.

```js
function isArrValEmptyCheck(value) {
  return !value || !(value instanceof Array) || value.length == 0 || value.length == 1 && value[0] == '';
}

console.log(isArrValEmptyCheck([""]));//returns true
console.log(isArrValEmptyCheck(["value1"]));//returns false
```

Sorry for the late response. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

there are two things:

- Change `Var` to `var`
- You can use `includes` method of `Array` as:

  ```
  var th = [] <==== chnage Var to var
  th.push("");
  if(th.includes($("#multiselect").val())) { <=== you can use includes method of array
      // DO whatever you want
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure var is lowercased.
2. You are accessing `th` as an array, so you’ll need to specify the index of the value you are checking: `th[0]`
3. Use triple equals, too: `.val()===th[0]`
4. Double check the jquery docs if you’re still running into trouble.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider:

1. You have a typo in the code above; `var` is valid; `Var` is invalid.
   Browser will aptly complain to solve this typo.
2. You are comparing an array to DOM value; this will always be false.
3. DOM is a costly process. Unless the value associated is dynamic, its better to read once, store value into a variable and continue processing instead of reading from DOM always.

You could choose to try something on these lines:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
let domValue = $("#multiselect").val();
arr.push(5);

arr.map((el, ix) => {
    if el === domValue return true; //or choose to do something else here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var th=[]; //It is var not Var
th.push("");
if($("#multiselect").val()==th[0]) // change th to th[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment so having to use an answer for now. Are you trying to check if an array has any values? If so you can use

```
if(th.length){
    // do something
}
```

If you want to check a normal variable for empty string you can simply use

```
if(th == “”){
    //do something
}
```